# Tell an AppleScript to Restart Itself

Tags: applescript, application-restart

I have an AppleScript saved as an application. When first run, it asks the user if they want to move it to the Applications folder. What I would like to be able to do is, after it's been moved, have the script quit itself and then reopen.

Obviously I can't say

```
tell me to quit
tell me to activate
```

...because it would stop running after the `quit` command.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the script from inside the script, and make sure to terminate the current running of it with a return (can skip the actual return command if it's the last line of the script

```
-- do stuff
display dialog "Here I am again"

-- set alias to the script
-- run the script
set myScript to path to me
run script myScript
-- end current iteration
return
```

You can break out of this script by canceling the dialog, but you'll probably want to set a condition to check whether to run the script again.

Comment: I get `Error -43 Folder does not exist`. I'm guessing that `path to me` still points to the old path, i.e. the path to the script at the time it was launched.

Comment: Yes, wherever you move the file, you need to then use that path. I didn't write your whole script for you, I simply showed you how to do the part you specifically didn't know how. You'll need to do something like: set myScript to (path to applications folder as string) & "myScriptName"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do this. Basically, You check if the application is running from the Applications folder. If it isn't, move it there, open another instance, and quit. Seems to work flawlessly. The activate in the beginning is because it seems that the application doesn't always move itself to the foreground:

```
--incase the application doesn't do this automagically
activate
set my_path to POSIX path of (path to me)
if my_path does not start with "/Applications/" then
    set new_path to "/Applications/" & quoted form of (my name & ".app")
    --"mv" wont move the application into the new location if it exists
    try
        do shell script "rm -rf " & new_path
    end try
    do shell script "mv -f " & quoted form of my_path & " " & new_path
    do shell script "open -n " & new_path & " &> /dev/null &"
    quit
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing.

First I enabled at by running the following command in Terminal (this only has to be done once)

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

then I have the following script

```
display dialog "running"
set mypath to POSIX path of (path to me)
set lun to open for access POSIX file "/tmp/springboard" with write permission
write "open " & mypath & linefeed to lun
close access lun
do shell script "at -f  /tmp/springboard +1 minute"
quit
```